# php returns junk characters at end of everything

Tags: php

php appears to be adding junk characters to the end of everything it returns on a friend's site. I'm not an admin on the server but I'd like to give an informed complaint to get this fixed.

The site is http://daytoncodebreakers.org. You can see some junk at the end of every page on the site (what appear to be question marks with something else in the middle). I originally thought this was a wordpress issue, but check out http://daytoncodebreakers.org/whereisini.php (which is just a call to phpinfo), and http://daytoncodebreakers.org/hello.php (which is just 'Hello World').

I'm not sure if this is the most appropriate site, but I think this is a server config issue, so I'm posting it here (rather than stackoverflow or superuser). Feel free to move it if want.

UPDATE: Problem seems to have fixed itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is being caused by mod_gzip and the fact that you do not have a final newline in your files. The newline problem is caused by serving Windows-encoded files on a Unix system.

Comment: Interesting. I noticed that when I look at the page with firefox on my mac I see the extra characters, but if I use curl or wget I don't see them.

Comment: @phil-hollenback That's because wget (and probably curl) do not by default accept gzip encoding. Try `wget --header="accept-encoding: gzip" http://daytoncodebreakers.org/hello.php`

Comment: I got this problem with CURL. I was requesting a JSON file and at the end of the response, I got this annoying % character. Including a new line return into the JSON solved the problem with the %. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini or php3.ini file on the server and see if you have [auto_append](http://www.hardcoder.com/scripting/php/include_files.php) set.  That appends a footer to every php page output.