# PHP weird characters after upgrade to 5.4

Tags: php

It seems PHP upgrade "broke" all the websites using PHP on my hosts. It adds junk characters in the footer on every page which uses PHP:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you provide the PHP source file and the generated HTML please.

Comment: http://wintercounter.me/
Here is an example for HTML output. For PHP sources i can't and not needed to. All pages using PHP have this problem, more than 100+ sites! Joomla, Wordpress, CodeIgniter, ExpressionEngine, and so on have these problems, even a simple echo 'Hello'; produces the same problem.

Comment: @wintercounter Which charset are these documents served with? See this related[?] SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701/storing-and-displaying-unicode-string-using-php-and-mysql

Comment: Using UTF-8 but PHP 5.4 should be native UTF-8 and it's not even a charset related problem. All UTF-8 special chars are displaying ok, only these four chars added to the footer since the upgrade. It's more like an UTF8-BOM but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was aptitude automaticly installed mod_php5filter.
Needed only:

```
a2dismod php5filter
```

Than everything worked ok.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a mod_gzip issue, caused by a missing final newline in the file.

It was answered previously by [Mark Wagner](https://serverfault.com/questions/223450/php-returns-junk-characters-at-end-of-everything).

Comment: It wasn't, as i said a simple `<?php echo 'Hello'; ?>` produced the same error. But i've fixed now, see my answer post.