# (Apache) Weird characters with Roundcube (PHP)

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

Yes, i saw all the questions about the weird characters at the end of a PHP script.
I will ask here because no solution from the internet and serverfault worked.

At this page: https://webmail.pixelwolf.ch/test/
there are some mysterious characters.
And that's the problem why my Roundcube does not work.

**What I already checked and tried:**
1. added AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
2. changed to AddDefaultCharset to ISO xxx (dont know the string right now)
3. php5filter disabled
4. gzip checked (according to [php returns junk characters at end of everything](https://serverfault.com/questions/223450/php-returns-junk-characters-at-end-of-everything)) but characters remain there

For notice: on my local server there aren't any of those characters. On local it just works.
So what can I check further?

Comment: Ok problem half-solved:

I just removed libapache2-mod-php5filter and instead of that I installed libapache2-mod-php5. I don't know whats wrong with that but that solved my problem. I even don't know why I installed filter instead of handler.

Comment: Filter seems to be the default with some package managers these days, I've also had php5-filter problems recently when creating new boxes. Good job working on your own solution.

Comment: @Tim: this problem caused me weeks of trouble. Bcause first we showed for problems by RC and now I just wanted to get rid of those characters. And tadaa: the headache causing problem is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem solved:

I just removed libapache2-mod-php5filter and instead of that I installed libapache2-mod-php5. I don't know whats wrong with that but that solved my problem. I even don't know why I installed filter instead of handler.

Answer (score 1):

You saved my day.

I had also this wired square / question mark character on every php page. In hexa, I had those in extra on every pages:

```
1F 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

It happends also only when receiving `gzip` content. Removing `libapache2-mod-php5filter` made the trick:

```
$ a2dismod php5filter
```

Comment: That's just an alternative to removing the php5filter.